# Pick one at a time twice Vs Pick 2 at one go - Conditional probability

Tags: probability

My problem a box has 2 Green, 3 Red, 5 Blue and 5 Black balls.
My understanding (conditional probability) is Probability of picking 1G and 1R should be same as (Probability of 1G) MULTIPLIED BY (Probability of 1R knowing 1st one was G).i.e.

p(1G and 1R) from 15 = P (1G from 15) * P(1R FROM 14)
But it is not working.
LHS = P(1G and 1R) = [(2 C 1)* (3 C 1)] / (15 C 2)= 6/(15*14/2).

RHS = (2/15)* (3/14) = 6/(15*14).
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

In the first one where you got $\dfrac{6}{15 \cdot 14/2}$, you allowed the outcome to be $G \rightarrow R$ OR $R \rightarrow G$.

Whereas in the second one where you got $\dfrac{6}{15 \cdot 14}$, you implicitly specified that the order should be $G \rightarrow R$, which is incorrect, since the problem only asked for choosing a green and a red without specifying the order.

Your second argument also works if you tweak it a bit:

\begin{align}
\Bbb P(1G \; 1R) & = \Bbb P(G \rightarrow R) + \Bbb P(R \rightarrow G) \\
& = \frac{2}{15} \cdot \frac{3}{14} + \frac{3}{15} \cdot + \frac{2}{14} \\
& = 2 \cdot \frac{6}{15 \cdot 14}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

RHS: $$P(G_1\cap R_2)+P(R_1\cap G_2)=P(G_1)P(R_2\mid G_1)+P(R_1)P(G_2\mid R_1)=\frac2{15}\frac3{14}+\frac3{15}\frac2{14}$$

LHS: $$\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{10}{0}}{\binom{15}{2}}$$

The outcomes agree.